# AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping, Mapping List of Types

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, automapper

I have the following code:

The structure of my project is like this:
[image]

My classes (relevant for this bug)

SizeEntity.cs

```
namespace DataObjects.EntityFramework
{
    public class SizeEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string SizeName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Size.cs (on business objects class library)

```
namespace BusinessObjects
{

    // Product business object
    // ** Enterprise Design Pattern: Domain Model, Identity Field, Foreign key mapping

    public class Size : BusinessObject
    {
        // ** Enterprise Design Pattern: Identity field pattern
        public Size()
        {
            // establish business rules
            AddRule(new ValidateRequired("SizeName"));
            AddRule(new ValidateLength("SizeName", 1, 3));
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string SizeName { get; set; }

    }
}
```

SizeDao.cs

```
public class SizeDao : ISizeDao
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor to initialize AutoMapper
        /// </summary>
        static SizeDao()
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<SizeEntity, Size>());
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<List<SizeEntity>, List<Size>>());
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Inserts size into database
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="size"></param>
        public void InsertSize(Size size)
        {
            using (var context = new ExamContext())
            {
                var entity = Mapper.Map<Size, SizeEntity>(size);

                context.Sizes.Add(entity);
                context.SaveChanges();

                // update business object with new id
                size.Id = entity.Id;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets all size from database
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Returns a list of Sizes</returns>
        public List<Size> GetSizes()
        {
            using (var context = new ExamContext())
            {
                var sizes = context.Sizes.ToList();
                return Mapper.Map<List<SizeEntity>, List<Size>>(sizes);
            }
        }
    }
```

I am getting the mapping error on the last line of this code.

return Mapper.Map, List>(sizes);

What am I missing here?

Error message is in the title:
AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping, Mapping List of Types

Update 1:

I removed that line suggest and still get:
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

```
Mapping types:
SizeEntity -> Size
DataObjects.EntityFramework.SizeEntity -> BusinessObjects.Size
```

Comment: Please provide error message

Comment: error is in the title, DTOs and entities are not in the same assembly :

Comment: No, the error is not in the title, you omitted the type names.

Comment: please see Update 1 for the entire error message

Comment: shame on the -1 for a completely valid question

Comment: No, shame on this being your 500+th question, and it lacks all research and doesn't contain a [mcve]. Anyway the problem is that you configure the mapper in the static constructor, which isn't run before your call to `Mapper.Map()`.

Comment: it doesnt lack any resarch, were you seeing my research (of 2 hours before posting the question?)

Comment: its already solved, by someone with better attitue.

Comment: I hope you realise the one with the wrong attitude might be you?
 You may want to read the [tour], [ask] and how to create a [mcve] to get what this site is about (building a collection of high-quality questions and answers that are helpful to many instead of just one) before asking your next question.

Comment: there is nothing irrelevant on the code, all the code is neccesary for the reader to understand the problem and come to a possible solution. Every line of code is 100% relevant.

Comment: No, [this code here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Fzml7S) is all that is relevant. 35 lines. **That** is a [mcve]. Sure, all code you show here causes _your_ problem, but that is irrelevant to the rest of the world and the later visitors of this question. **That** is why you should create a [mcve].

Comment: yeah whatever,.,.

Answer (score 2):

For first you should remove the initialization of the mapping where you specify the `List` of objects, you just need to define the mapping with the base objects. That initialization would lead to an empty result when you call `Map` method.

```
static SizeDao()
{
    Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<SizeEntity, Size>());

    // This is not needed.
    // Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<List<SizeEntity>, List<Size>>());
}
```

Another thing, as suggested @CodeCaster, don't put your mapping definition in the static constructor, but, for example, in the entry point of the whole application and verify that those lines get called before you invoke the `Map` method.

Comment: please ellaborate as its still not working with your correction

Answer (score 0):

Because Automapper didnt work, then I had to do the following:

```
 /// <summary>
        /// Gets all size from database
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Returns a list of Sizes</returns>
        public List<Size> GetSizes()
        {
            using (var context = new ExamContext())
            {
                var sizes = context.SizeEntities.ToList();

                //Convert SizeEntities list to Size (Business Objects) list
                var targetList = sizes
                  .Select(x => new Size() { Id = x.Id, SizeName =  x.SizeName})
                  .ToList();

                return targetList;
                //return Mapper.Map<List<SizeEntity>, List<Size>>(sizes);
            } 
        }
```